# npm live-server not opening browser or watching changes

Tags: angularjs, npm

I am currently trying to follow the Angular 2 quick start guide:
https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

I have installed the npm packages as shown in the first step and edited the package.json scripts section so that it reads:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "live-server"
  }
```

When I run `npm start` in the terminal it shows the command with a flashing cursor but doesn't open a new window and any changes made to the source do not refresh the window if I open one manually.

[image: live server command prompt]

Is there something that i've missed in order to get the server to auto load browser and refresh on change?

All files in source folder are on the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as you while following the Angular 2 quick start guide. Live-server defaults to the address `127.0.0.1` and port `8080`. In my case there was a conflict with live-server and another program trying to run on the same address and port.

In case it's just the browser that's not launching, you can try to access `127.0.0.1:8080` directly in your browser and check if that page works. You can also go in your package.json and try adding a custom port on the scripts line like this :

```
"start": "live-server --port=8181"
```

This could help solve whatever conflict you might have on port `8080`. After I got it to launch the browser, I also had issues where it didn't reload automatically and switching to port 8181 solved that problem as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Its annoying that it doesn't throw an error to the console to tell you of the conflict though.

Comment: No problem. I agree, it would have saved quite some time if live-server detected the conflict and threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the commandline parameter --open

```
    "start": "live-server --open=./app/"
```